# i am using sleep method of class Thread in java, can anyone tell how avoid this thing

Tags: java

i am using sleep because one method is taking time to execute and i  want to execute next method when it is completed. this is what i am trying.

```
method1();
Thread.sleep(3000);
method2();
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to call Thread.sleep, as method2 should not be called until method 1 is complete.

Comment: Your question seems vague, and confusing. Are you executing those methods in same Thread? If yes, then they will execute one after the other. No need to do Thread.sleep()

Answer (score 4):

To run one method after another you can do

```
method1();
method2();
```

There is no need to sleep between method calls.

---

> my method1 is executing some shellscript

In this case you should have something like

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);
// wait for the process to finish.
process.waitFor();
```

Comment: @OP `i want to execute next method when it is completed` --> exactly what above code does.

Comment: @All: actually my method1 is executing some shellscript(this script fires command on diffrent servers and then after searching i t writes the required data into txt file) at backend and writing it to some other file so if i write without producing delay i am not getting values which i am reading through method2.

Comment: In that case, the simplest thing to do is to should wait for the process to finish

Comment: @peter :here my method1 is calling one method which executes shellscript and that shell get executed on diffrent server so in whole process it is taking some time and at that time my method2 tries to read files which are generated by method1.....all this is going well when i am using sleep() for some second but i dont want to use sleep method ,i need other solution.

Comment: @adityasingh I understand that, and the better solution is to wait for the shell script to finish.  It doesn't matter that it's running on another machine.